# jQuery UI: Save height and position of divs in cookie

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui, jquery-cookie

I have a few div boxes which are sortable and resizable (with jQuery UI). Now I want to save their position (sortable) and their height (resizable), so that I can read out their values and give the divs their position and size they had.

**How my site looks like this**
[image]

As you can see: I can sort the `.panelgroup`'s in .`.content_left` and `.content_right`. In addition I can resize all the `.panelcontent`'s heights

And now I want to save the position of each `.panelgroup` and the height of each `.panelcontent`.

**HTML**

```
<script>
$( ".panelcontent" ).resizable({handles: \'s\'});
$(".content_right, .content_left").sortable({
    handle: ".panelheadbar",
    connectWith: ".ui-sortable",
    appendTo: "body",
    helper: "clone",
    zIndex: 1000
}).disableSelection();
$( ".togglepanelcontent" ).click(function() {
    var icon = $( this );
    icon.closest( ".panelgroup" ).find( ".panelcontent" ).toggle("slide", {direction: "up", duration: "slow", easing: "easeOutQuart"});
});
</script>
<div class="content_left ui-sortable">
    <div id="modul_1" class="panelgroup">
        <div class="panelheadbar pgrau">Module 1<div class="togglepanelcontent"><span>--</span></div></div>
        <div id="pc_1" class="panelcontent ui-resizable">
            text
        </div>
        <br>
    </div>
    <div id="modul_2" class="panelgroup">
        <div class="panelheadbar pgrau">Module 2<div class="togglepanelcontent"><span>--</span></div></div>
        <div id="pc_2" class="panelcontent ui-resizable">
            text
        </div>
        <br>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="content_mid"></div>
<div class="content_right ui-sortable">
    <div id="modul_3" class="panelgroup">
        <div class="panelheadbar pgrau">Module 3<div class="togglepanelcontent"><span>--</span></div></div>
        <div id="pc_3" class="panelcontent ui-resizable">
            text
        </div>
        <br>
    </div>
    <div id="modul_4" class="panelgroup">
        <div class="panelheadbar pgrau">Module 4<div class="togglepanelcontent"><span>--</span></div></div>
        <div id="pc_4" class="panelcontent ui-resizable">
            text
        </div>
        <br>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.panelheadbar       {   padding: 5px; font-weight: bold; color: #000; overflow: hidden; height: auto; cursor: move;
                        border-bottom: 1px solid <?=$usercolor_css?>; }
.pgrau              {   background-color: #ccc; }
.panelcontent       {   overflow: auto; overflow-x: hidden;padding: 10px; top: 0px; left: 0px;
                        background-color: #FFF; border-left: 1px solid #333; border-right: 1px solid #333; border-bottom: 1px solid #333; }
.togglepanelcontent {   float: right; cursor: pointer; }
```

Do you know how to save these values so that the website instantly displays the previous height and position?

Answer (score 0):

```
var sortableElements, coordinates;

$(".content_left").sortable({
  update: function( event, ui ) {

      sortableElements = $(this).sortable("toArray");
      console.log( sortableElements ); // ID's of sortable items in current order

      sortableElements.forEach(function(item) {
          coordinates = document.getElementById(item).getBoundingClientRect();
          console.log(coordinates); // object of coordinates for each sortable item
      });

      console.log(ui.originalPosition) // object of original coordinates for moved item
      console.log(ui.position) // object of current coordinates for moved item

      // Set a cookie with array of items
      localStorage.setItem("cookieName", JSON.stringify(sortableElements));
  }
});
```

I provided a pretty well commented fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/aqtq64n1/1/. Open your console and check it out.

Also, check out the .sortable API actions: http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/

You can call .update, then from there call $(this).sortable("toArray") to get an array of the item's ID's in their current order

Then I looped that array and used the amazing .getBoundingClientRect() function to return an object of coordinates for each item.

Sortables' .update action returns a bunch of data on the moved item also (ie originalPosition and position) which I included just to show you, but I would just use .getBoundingClientRect().

Then I just used localStorage to save the item as you wanted.

I didn't do the height stuff, but I'm sure you can figure that out. In the .forEach loop just get each items .height() and append it to the coordinates object.

Hope this helps!

Comment: It does not save the position for me :/ I just implemented your code into `$(".content_right, .content_left").sortable({` When i reload the page, all is as it was before

Comment: yeah man, you need to do more work yourself. this is just a starting point